# Json from backend which is built with Django Rest Framework is somehow undefined at frontend, built with React

Tags: python, json, reactjs, django, axios

I'm currently trying to learn the integration of Django Rest Framework and React.js, the former for the backend and the latter for the frontend, by building a simple to-do application.

views.py

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from . import models
from .serializers import ToDoSerializer, ToDoContainerSerializer

class ToDoContainerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = models.ToDoContainer.objects.all().order_by('created')
    serializer_class = ToDoContainerSerializer
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework.serializers import HyperlinkedModelSerializer
from . import models as todo_model
from rest_framework.serializers import ReadOnlyField

class ToDoContainerSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    created_by = ReadOnlyField(source='created_by.id')

    class Meta:
        model = todo_model.ToDoContainer
        fields = (
            'url', 'id',
            'created_by',
            'todos_name',
            'todos_important',
            'todos_items_count',
        )
        extra_kwargs = {
            'url': {
                'view_name': 'todos:todocontainer-detail',
            },
        }
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from core.models import TimeStampedModel
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator

class ToDoContainer(TimeStampedModel):

    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        user_model.User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="todo_container")
    todos_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    todos_important = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def todos_items_count(self):
        todo_items = len(self.todo.all())
        return int(todo_items)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.todos_name)
```

I built the views, serializers, models like above, and it seemed api generated properly like the below.
[image: todos api]

And I tried to get the json of the above to frontend by using the axios module like the below.

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import ToDoCard from './ToDoCard';

class ToDoLists extends React.Component {
    state = {
        isLoading: true,
        toDos: []
    };
    getToDos = async () => {
        const { results } = await axios.get("/backend/todos-api/todo_container.json");
        console.log(results) //Errors here, 'results' is undefined
        this.setState({ toDos: results, isLoading: false })
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.getToDos();
    }
    render() {
        const { isLoading, toDos } = this.state;
        return (<section className="container">
            {isLoading ? (
                <div className="loader">
                    <span className="loader__text">Loading...</span>
                </div>
            ) : (
                    <div className="toDos">
                        {
                            toDos.map(toDo => {
                                return <ToDoCard
                                    key={toDo.id}
                                    id={toDo.id}
                                    todos_name={toDo.todos_name}
                                    todos_important={toDo.todos_important}
                                />
                            })
                        }
                    </div>
                )
            }
        </section>)
    }
}

export default ToDoLists;
```

But the 'results' from 'axios.get("/backend/todos-api/todo_container.json");' was undefined, despite backend seemed fine like the below.

django result

```
[04/Jan/2021 20:38:07] "GET /backend/todos-api/todo_container.json HTTP/1.1" 200 372
```

I also set settings like the below and tried 'axios.get("/backend/todos-api/todo_container/");' but the result was the same. 'results' was undefined, and backend seemed fine.

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10,
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer'
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.FormParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser'
    )
}

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'https://localhost:3000',
    'https://127.0.0.1:3000',
)
```

django result

```
[04/Jan/2021 20:32:13] "GET /backend/todos-api/todo_container/ HTTP/1.1" 200 364
```

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should add append `?format=json` instead of `.json` to the url. Unless you changed the url to be specifically ".json". But it's weird that you get a `200` response from both:

```
 "/backend/todos-api/todo_container.json"
```

and

```
"/backend/todos-api/todo_container/"
```

can you post your urls.py?

Also try changing to, since you're unpacking the object, I think there's no field named `results` in the axios response, but there is `data` which is the actual json:

```
const { data } = await axios.get("/backend/todos-api/todo_container/");
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Your answer worked for me!! I changed 'results' to 'data' , and axios finally received json object. Additionally, I needed to fix the react child component a little bit. And finally it worked! Thank you very much again for your help!